# Amplifier detector circuit simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, instrumentation-amplifier

I wanted to do [falstad.com](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/) simulation of the circuit([link to schematic](https://www.ebay.pl/itm/CsI-Tl-6-6-25mm-scintillation-detector-with-SiPM-for-spectrometry-res-6/224751803724)):

[image]

Falstad isn't familiar to me, so I'll be grateful for showing me how it should be drawn.

I think detector could be replaced by voltage generator.

I also wanted to know what is the idea of the third amplifier, that one which produces pulses with 500 \$\mu s\$ wide. Is it also amplifying the output? Why, I guess, non-inverting input of the amplifier is connected to 1/2 \$V_{cc}\$?

Comment: Haven't you drawn the circuit? Don't you know why you used the third op-amp. If not then you need to provide details where you got the schematic from. Site rules.

Comment: @Andyaka - "*you need to provide details where you got the schematic from. Site rules*" FYI no, it isn't site rules to provide that info for *questions*, only [for *answers*](/help/referencing). It would be helpful for the OP to provide context, of course, but helpful =/= site rules.

Comment: That sounds like an arbitrary decision.

Comment: I think the third amplifier produces a more consistent and normalized pulse for counting purposes. I assume the point of this is to build a scintillation pulse counter, right? But I am not really sure.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, the point is to build a scintillation pulse counter.

Comment: @Andyaka - It's SE site-wide policy, so if you want to make a point about that, then [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for you to raise it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the detector should be a current source proportional to the incident light.

Answer (score 0):

That last op amp is a 2-pole low pass filter using a Sallen-Key configuration.

The detector can be replaced by a voltage generator.  However, it's up to you to configure the voltage generator to behave like your detectorl